# matplotlib ylabels disappear upon creating second subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the MWE below, the y-label and ticks disappear. It seems to happen only with a few specific combinations of twiny and pandas for the other plot. The MWE is easily solved by changing the order in which the two subplots are created, but in my full script this is not as straightforward.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how it can be solved?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100))

def plot_twin(ax):
    ax.plot([0,1])
    ax.set_ylabel('test')

    # Add return time axis to plot
    other_ax = ax.twiny()    
    return

def plot_df(df,ax):
    df.plot(kind='box',ax=ax)
    return

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
plot_twin(ax2)
plot_df(df,ax1)
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I get the axis displayed okay with the above code on matplotlib by 1.4.3 and pandas 0.16.1. Does adding `sharey=False` to `plt.subplots(1,2)` help? Maybe increase wspace `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)`.

Comment: @EdSmith Thanks, but no, that doesn't help. I use matplotlib 1.5.1 and pandas 0.18.1 btw

Comment: what happens if you add `fig.tight_layout()` before you show anything.

Comment: @PaulH that doesn't help either

Comment: This isn't a matplotlib issue. It's a pandas issue. For whatever reason, pandas is clearing out the labels of the subplots when you use it to make your boxplots.  If you switch the order of your calls to `plot_df` and `plot_twin`, the issue goes away. Similarly, if you just use `ax1.boxplot`, you don't see this problem either